# Change color of primeng input-switch

Tags: html, css, primeng

I have the following p-inputSwitch.

```
<p-inputSwitch class="ml-1 mr-1 align-middle"
               (onChange)="setDefaultValues($event)"
               [ngModel]="defaultValuesToggle">
</p-inputSwitch>
```

Is there a way to change the color from blue when selected? I have tried the following, but nothing changes the color:

```
.p-inputswitch {
    background: red !important;
}
.p-inputswitch .p-inputswitch-slider {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the "selected" state to the selector by adding the class `p-inputswitch-checked` to `.p-inputswitch` and also add `::ng-deep` infront of the selector to penetrate [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation):

```
::ng-deep .p-inputswitch.p-inputswitch-checked .p-inputswitch-slider {
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: This worked. But when i add the same scss in style.scss or index.scss to apply this globally for all the input switches across the application, it doesn't works at all. Why ? Please help.

Comment: @Tanzeel Try changing to `background: purple !important;`. Your global style might be getting overridden because of specificity.

Comment: Yes, `!important` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: This gave me the info needed to do it for the checkbox. Thanks!